# Cannot Implicity convert IEnumerable<int> to int Linq Query

Tags: linq, list

I have a custom class as follows

```
public class PhoneTypeListInfo
    {

        public string AccountNum { get; set; }
        public int PhoneType { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNum { get; set; }

    }
```

I need to retrieve the `PhoneType`, by the `PhoneNumber` value I provide the query.

So I am using this Method and Query.

```
protected int RetrievePhoneType(List<PhoneTypeListInfo> xPhoneTypeList, string info )
        {
            int type;
            type = xPhoneTypeList.Where(p => p.PhoneNum == info).Select(p => p.PhoneType);


            return type;
        }
```

is this not the correct way, or do I need to cast it as `int`?

**EDIT**
It looks like there might be multiple accounts that could have the same phone number. I need to pass an additional where clause. AND then use the `FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: If you're looking for just one result, add `.FirstOrDefault()` to the end of the query.  `Select` returns an `IEnumerable<T>` (a collectoin), *even* if there's only one result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Select` method is going to return a collection. But the type of type variable is of type `Int`. That is the reason you are getting this error.

May be you should consider taking a single item from the collection.

If you want to take the first item from the collection , Use LINQ `FirstOrDefault` method.

```
int type = xPhoneTypeList.Where(p => p.PhoneNum == info).Select(p => p.PhoneType)
                                                                        .FirstOrDefault();
```

This will give you the first item from the collection. If the collection is empty, It will give you the default value, which is 0.(*Assuming PhoneType is a numeric type*)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid returning an IEnumerable collection of all possible answers to the select query, even though you think there should only be one, append your LINQ with

`.FirstOrDefault();`

and it will return a single integer. There are a number of additional methods that can be used (or chained) together to facilitate exactly what you require.